# How can i make my bitmap passed to another activity be visible?

Tags: android

I have two activities with their own gridviews and Adapters and I want to pass a data(containg both image (in the form of bitmap resources)and text) from one activity to the other. The problem I am having is with the image. It does not display on the gridview only the text does and also when I try to add another data, it overwrites the former one. Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or what I need to do? (I want this application to function like when you are adding a favourite online radio station to a preset list).
Below are the acitivies (cropped)

first activity

```
com_res=getResources();

    Comm_AppsList=new ArrayList<Appis_Infos>();
    Comm_AppsList.add(new Appis_Infos(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(com_res, R.drawable.skype), "Skype","com.skype.raider"));
    Comm_AppsList.add(new Appis_Infos(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(com_res, R.drawable.yahoomessenger),"Messenger","com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.im"));
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();

    String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
    String menuItemName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
    int menuappname=info.position;

        Appis_Infos AppName = Comm_AppsList.get(menuappname);
        Bitmap itemB=AppName.getIcon();//This is what I need as the image to the other class but when I use it in the Bitmapfactory I get an error


        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(com_res, menuItemIndex);
        Intent favList=new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),FavouriteListAppis.class);
        Bundle Bbundle=new Bundle();
        Bbundle.putParcelable("KeyB", bmp);

        favList.putExtra("KeyName", AppName.getName());
        startActivity(favList);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), AppName.getName()+" has been added to your favourite list "+menuItemIndex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}
 class CommAppis_Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context AIcontext;
private List<Appis_Infos>AdList;

CommAppis_Adapter(Context Aicontext, List<Appis_Infos> aDlist){
AIcontext=Aicontext;
AdList=aDlist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return AdList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int it_position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return AdList.get(it_position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int id_position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id_position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int Vposition, View Aview, ViewGroup Vparent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Appis_Infos appsData=AdList.get(Vposition);
    Comm_Viewholder holder=null;

    if(Aview==null){
        LayoutInflater apps_inflater=LayoutInflater.from(AIcontext);
        Aview=apps_inflater.inflate(R.layout.comm_appis, null);
        holder=new Comm_Viewholder();

        holder.apps_icons=(ImageView)Aview.findViewById(R.id.comm_imageview);
        holder.apps_name=(TextView)Aview.findViewById(R.id.comm_tvName);


        Aview.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder=(Comm_Viewholder)Aview.getTag();
    }

    holder.apps_icons.setImageBitmap(appsData.getIcon());
    holder.apps_name.setText(appsData.getName());

    return Aview;
}

}
class Comm_Viewholder{
ImageView apps_icons;
TextView apps_name;

}
```

The second activity

```
Fav_gridview=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gvfavist);
    Resources fav_res=getResources();

    if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        bmp = bundle.getParcelable("KeyB");

        favapp=getIntent().getExtras().getString("KeyName");


    }
    Fav_AppsList=new ArrayList<Appis_Infos>();
        Fav_AppsList.add(new Appis_Infos( bmp, favapp,"com.skype.raider"));



        class FavAppis_Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context AIcontext;
private List<Appis_Infos>AdList;

FavAppis_Adapter(Context Aicontext, List<Appis_Infos> aDlist){
AIcontext=Aicontext;
AdList=aDlist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return AdList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int it_position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return AdList.get(it_position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int id_position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id_position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int Vposition, View Aview, ViewGroup Vparent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Appis_Infos appsData=AdList.get(Vposition);
    Fav_Viewholder holder=null;

    if(Aview==null){
        LayoutInflater apps_inflater=LayoutInflater.from(AIcontext);
        Aview=apps_inflater.inflate(R.layout.favlist_appis, null);
        holder=new Fav_Viewholder();

        holder.apps_icons=     (ImageView)Aview.findViewById(R.id.favlistimageview);
        holder.apps_name=(TextView)Aview.findViewById(R.id.favlisttvName);


        Aview.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder=(Fav_Viewholder)Aview.getTag();
    }

    holder.apps_icons.setImageBitmap(appsData.getIcon());
    holder.apps_name.setText(appsData.getName());

    return Aview;
}

}
class Fav_Viewholder{
ImageView apps_icons;
TextView apps_name;

}
```

their common class

```
public class Appis_Infos {
private Bitmap AIcon;
private String Aname;
private String packname;

public Appis_Infos(Bitmap icon, String name, String pname){
    AIcon=icon;
    Aname=name;
    packname=pname;
}
public void setIcon(Bitmap icon){
    AIcon=icon;
}
public Bitmap getIcon(){
    return AIcon;
}
public void setName(String name){
    Aname=name;
}
public String getName(){
    return Aname;
}
public void setPname(String pname){
    packname=pname;
}
public String getPname(){
    return packname;
}
}
```

Comment: don't try to pass bitmap using intent..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply name you Bitmap as static first.

then create a method like

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(){
    return bitmap;
}
```

then you can simply call from other activities,
bitmapwantedclass.getBitmap();

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks but making the Bitmap staic does not help as it keeps the last image which it uses to fill other classes where the getBitmap() is called.

Comment: Do you know this application tunein?Its an online radio app. What I want my second activity to do is like when you are playing a radio station in tunein and then add the station to your preset list. It just sends the icon and the name of that radio station to the Preset List.

Comment: if you are using any adapter for populating list use settag propertie in the adapter and use gettag property when you require those list item.

Comment: How do I implement this as I have my settag and get tags in my adapter for the two activities?